# How to use Forms with VueX and script setup? Do you use v-model?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

EDIT:

Should I not use VueX at all because it's outdated and Pinia is what people use nowadays?

---

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-script-setup-with-vuex-hmrk5d?file=src/store.ts

I'm trying to make it so you fill in the form info, click "save" button, and it displays in the "Results" section below the form.

I have the whole VueX store created. Mutations and actions and all that already done. I just don't know how to implement them into form actions?

Do I use "v-model"? Or do I create dispatch functions? Where do I put the dispatch functions if so? How do the "value" and "name" attributes of the form elements factor into this? Is the process here the same as if I was submitting the form info to a server/database instead of the template?

Can someone help me with this code?

---

**store.ts**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: () => ({
    gender: '',
    name: '',
    job: '',
  }),
  getters: {
    currentGender: (state) => state.gender,
    currentName: (state) => state.name,
    currentJob: (state) => state.job,
  },
  actions: {
    changeGender({ commit }, { gender }) {
      commit('CHOOSE_GENDER')
    },
    changeName({ commit }, { name }) {
      commit('CHOOSE_NAME', name)
    },
    changeJob({ commit }, { job }) {
      commit('CHOOSE_GENDER', job)
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    CHOOSE_GENDER(state, gender) {
      state.gender = gender
    },
    CHOOSE_NAME(state, name) {
      state.name = name
    },
    CHOOSE_JOB(state, job) {
      state.job = job
    },
  },
})
```

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
  <p>Vue Form Test</p>
  <form>
    <div class="nes-field">
      <label for="name_field">Character Name</label>
      <input placeholder="Enter name" type="text" name="name" id="name_field" class="nest-input"/>
    </div>
    <section>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="Male" class="nes-radio" name="gender" />
        <span>Male</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="Female" class="nes-radio" name="gender" />
        <span>Female</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" class="nes-radio" />
        <span>Other</span>
      </label>
    </section>
    <div class="nes-select job">
      <select name="job" id="default_select">
        <option value="" disabled>pick a job</option>
        <option value="mage">Mage</option>
        <option value="fighter">Fighter</option>
        <option value="druid">Druid</option>
        <option value="sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button>Save</button>
  </form>
  <br />
  <h1>Results:</h1>
  <h3>Name: {{name}}</h3>
  <h3>Gender: {{gender}}</h3>
  <h3>Job: {{job}}</h3>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const store = useStore()
const name = computed(()=>store.getters.currentName)
const gender = computed(()=>store.getters.currentGender)
const job = computed(()=>store.getters.currentJob)

const onSubmit = () => {

}
</script>
```

Comment: I highly suggest Pinia! And yes you can use v-model in your forms! Pinia provides a method called storeToRefs() that allows your values to keep their reactivity!

Comment: Think of store `getters` as a component's `computed`. You don't want to write a `computed` which returns a `data` member. Similarly, there's no need to write store getters to return a state prop. You can get it from state directly. This goes for both `vuex` and `pinia`. What's simplified in `pinia` is that, instead of having both `actions` and `mutations`, you only have `actions`. And those `actions` can safely mutate `state`, so they act like `vuex`'s mutations, except they can also be `async`. `pinia` is simpler and more intuitive than `vuex`.

Answer (score 0):

With `pinia` you don't even need `actions`***<sup>1</sup>*** to keep a form in sync with a store ***<sup>2</sup>***.
You use `storeToRefs`:

```js
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia
const { createApp } = Vue

const useStore = defineStore("store", {
  state: () => ({
    gender: "",
    name: "",
    job: ""
  })
})

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp({
  setup: () => ({
    ...storeToRefs(useStore()),
    genders: ["Male", "Female", "Other"],
    jobs: ["mage", "fighter", "druid", "sorcerer"],
    capitalize: (str) => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1)
  })  
})
app.use(pinia)
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pinia/2.0.29/pinia.iife.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Vue Form Test</p>
  <form>
    <div class="nes-field">
      <label for="name_field">Character Name</label>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter name"
        type="text"
        name="name"
        id="name_field"
        class="nest-input"
        v-model="name"
      />
    </div>
    <section>
      <label v-for="g in genders" :key="g">
        <input
          type="radio"
          :value="g"
          class="nes-radio"
          name="gender"
          v-model="gender"
        />
        <span v-text="g" />
      </label>
    </section>
    <div class="nes-select job">
      <select name="job" v-model="job">
        <option value="" disabled>pick a job</option>
        <option v-for="j in jobs" :key="j" :value="j">
          {{ capitalize(j) }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br />
  <h1>Results:</h1>
  <h3>Name: {{name}}</h3>
  <h3>Gender: {{gender}}</h3>
  <h3>Job: {{job}}</h3>
</div>
```

---

With `vuex` you could create a computed for each field. Example:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'
import store from '/path/to/store'
const name = computed({
  get() { return store.state.name },
  set(val) { store.commit('CHOOSE_NAME', val)
})
// now you can use `name` with `v-model`, as above.
// and you do the same for `gender` and `job`.
```

An alternative is to use `:value` + `@input` pattern, which is pretty much the same, except you place the `get` from the above `computed` into `:value` and the `set` function into `@input`. Example:

```html
<input
  :value="store.state.name"
  @input="(e) => store.commit('CHOOSE_NAME', e.target.value)" />
```

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - `pinia` groups both `actions` and `mutations` under `actions`: they can mutate `state` and can be `async`.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - if you don't want this instant save-to-store functionality and you'd rather let the user choose when to save, you can save the initial store value in the component, create a local state (reactive object) from that initial value and use this reactive object in the form. You compare the current object's value with the initial one and enable the save button when the values differ. The save button should call a function which writes to the store's state.